# Android Listview Overwrite data instead of append

Tags: android, listview

In my Android application, I am using webservices with index values (for eg.

`https://mysampleurl.com/sampledata?username=""&&password=""&&startindex="1"&&endindex="10"`)

and pass the extracted data to a `BaseAdapter` via an `arraylist` and display the result in a `listview.`

When the `listview` reaches the bottom, Using `asynctask` I will increment the index values (for eg.

`https://mysampleurl.com/sampledata?username=""&&password=""&&startindex="11"&&endindex="20")`.

I will receive the data and store it in `arraylist` and it goes on.

But when I pass array list values to adapter, it overwrites the existing data instead of appending with previous values.

```
    @Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    System.out.println("position:"+position);
}
```

I have checked this above code in some other examples, at first it gives values like 1,2,.....10. and at second time it gives 1,2,3,.....20. But in my application it always return the values upto 1,2,3......10.

Could some one tell me what mistake I have done?

```
public ContentListAdapter (Context context, ArrayList<CommonData> contentList) 
{
    ctxt = context;
    this.ContentList = contentList;
    contentListRowInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    mSelectedItemsIds=new SparseBooleanArray();
    checkBoxState=new boolean[contentList.size()];
}

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return (filteredContentList == null)?0:filteredContentList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return filteredContentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) 
    {
        return position;
    }

    Here only i pass the values and check the position

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        ContentListActivity.adapterFlag = false;
        DocumentListViewHolder viewHolder = null;
         if (convertView == null || convertView.getTag() == null) {
            convertView = contentListRowInflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.content_list_row, null);
              viewHolder = new DocumentListViewHolder();
            viewHolder.ivDocumentdoctypeIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivDocumentTypeIcon);
            viewHolder.tvDocumentTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvDocumentTitle);
            viewHolder.tvsubitemcount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvsubitemcount);
            viewHolder.ivarrowlauncher = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.arrowlauncher);

            viewHolder.checkboxselection=(CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkboxdeletion);
            checkBoxSelection=viewHolder.checkboxselection;
             viewHolder.checkboxselection.setChecked(checkBoxState[position]);
            viewHolder.ivarrowlauncher = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.arrowlauncher);
             mainlayoutrl = (RelativeLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.clrrlmain);
             sublayoutll = (LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.clrowll);
             arrowlayoutll = (LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.clarrowll);    
             final Context context = ContentListActivity.contentListActivity;
             if(viewHolder.checkboxselection.isChecked()) {
                                  mainlayoutrl.setBackgroundColor(ctxt.getResources().getColor(R.color.checkboxrowselect));
                  sublayoutll.setBackgroundColor(ctxt.getResources().getColor(R.color.checkboxrowselect));
                  arrowlayoutll.setBackgroundColor(ctxt.getResources().getColor(R.color.checkboxrowselect));
             } else  {
                  mainlayoutrl.setBackgroundColor(ctxt.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                  sublayoutll.setBackgroundColor(ctxt.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                  arrowlayoutll.setBackgroundColor(ctxt.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
             }

             sublayoutll.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
            if (Config.networkConnectionCheck(context)) {
        if(filteredContentList.get(position).type.equalsIgnoreCase("FOLDER")) {
        ContentListActivity.ListarrowClick(position+1,context);
                        } else if (refreshFlag == false) {
        ContentListActivity.oldviewContent(position+1,context);
                        } else

                    } else {
                        ContentListActivity.oldofflineViewContent(position+1,context);
                    }
                }
             });

             arrowlayoutll.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
             {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                    ContentListActivity.ListarrowClick(position+1,context);
                }
                 });
             viewHolder.ivfilesDownload=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.document_list_row_download_imageview);

             //newly added by venkat 
             viewHolder.ivfilesdownloaded=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.document_list_row_downloaded_imageview);

             viewHolder.tvDocumentDescription=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvdocumentdescription);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (DocumentListViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        viewHolder.tvDocumentTitle.setText(filteredContentList.get(position).name);
            String desc = filteredContentList.get(position).versiondescription;
        if (desc != null) {
            viewHolder.tvDocumentDescription.setText(filteredContentList
                    .get(position).versiondescription);
        }
        String doctype = filteredContentList.get(position).type;
        String subitemcount = filteredContentList.get(position).subitemcount;
        if (doctype.equalsIgnoreCase(ctxt.getResources()
                .getString(R.string.pdf))) {
            viewHolder.ivDocumentdoctypeIcon
                    .setImageResource(R.drawable.pdfbigicon);
        } else if (doctype.equalsIgnoreCase(ctxt.getResources().getString(
                R.string.swf))) {
            viewHolder.ivDocumentdoctypeIcon
                    .setImageResource(R.drawable.flashbigicon);
        } if(doctype.equalsIgnoreCase(ctxt.getResources().getString(
                R.string.folder)))
        {
            viewHolder.ivarrowlauncher.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        if (filteredContentList.get(position).isupdateavailable
                .equalsIgnoreCase(ctxt.getResources().getString(
                        R.string.update_false_status))) {
        } else if (filteredContentList.get(position).isupdateavailable
                .equalsIgnoreCase(ctxt.getResources().getString(
                        R.string.update_true_status))) {
                    WebAPI webapi = new WebAPI(ctxt);
                            if (LoginHandler.arraylistdata.size() == 1) {
                                user_id = LoginHandler.arraylistdata.get(0)
                                        .getUserid();
                                org_id = LoginHandler.arraylistdata.get(0)
                                        .getOrgId();
                            } else {
                                user_id = LoginHandler.arraylistdata.get(
                                        OrgListActivity.selected_org_pos)
                                        .getUserid();
                                org_id = LoginHandler.arraylistdata.get(
                                        OrgListActivity.selected_org_pos)
                                        .getOrgId();
                            }
                            LoginDatabaseHandler loginDBHandler = new LoginDatabaseHandler(
                                    ctxt);
                            loginDBHandler.open();
                            int toglState = loginDBHandler.checkOffToggleState(
                                    user_id, org_id, filteredContentList
                                            .get(position).dockey.toString());              
                                }
                            } else
                                versionUpdate(position, ctxt);
                        }
                    });
        }
        /*ends*/        
        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: Show code of your adapter..

Comment: If you receive the data then you should add() it to your existing arraylist..After that call  adapter.notifydatasetchanged().

Comment: I have added some important part of the code of my adapter @KanakSony . please have a look